# matching fields with fscanf

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

I'm parsing in C program lines of text having the following format:

`integer1 (string) SingleSymbol integer2 integer3 integer4`

e.g.

`1001 (abba) S 2000 3000 4000`

So I read them one by one, however I want to extract only few fields, in particular `string` and `integer2`, I only managed to come up with this:

`fscanf(fp, "%*d (%[^)])", comm`)

Is it possible to match on the 4th field in one `fscanf` expression?

Comment: why not doing simply `fscanf(fp,"%*s (%s) %*s %d %*s %*s",s,&i);`

Comment: note that your question seems truncated.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @Mark actually forget my comment, I deleted it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `fscanf(fp,"%*s (%s) ...` will not work - `)` is read into `string`.  Perhaps `fscanf(fp,"%*s (%[^)]) %*s %d %*s %*s",s,&i);`.  Still this is fragile.  Better to read the line and then use `sscanf()`

Comment: @Mark What should happen if the line of text does not match the format?

Answer (score 0):

Why not read all the parameters as `string` using a delimiter of "space"?
After you will read all of them into an array you can convert the ones you want to `int` etc.